# A graph where for each pair of vertices, there exist a vértice adjacent to both and a vértice adjacent to neither

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, conjectures

Can we construct a simple $G=(V, E) $ so that for any pair $u, v\in V $, there is a vértix $x$ adjacent to both, as well as a vertix $y$ that is not adjacent to either $u, v$. So, $ux, vx \in E$ and $uy, vy\notin E $. I believe this to be impossible, and therefore conjecture that if every pair of people have a mutual friend, then one pair doesn't have a mutual stranger.

Can someone find a counterexample?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of such a graph.

[image]

It is the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of two triangles. (The Cartesian product of two complete graphs, each on at least three vertices, would work just as well.)